# Disable 'OK Google' recognition without completely disabling Google app

Tags: google, google-apps, voice-recognition, gboard, ok-google

I find the 'OK Google' always-on voice recognition to be creepy and intrusive.

At the same time, I find the voice entry for GBoard keyboard to be very useful.

If you completely disable the Google app, 'OK Google' recognition is disabled, but so is the voice entry for the GBoard keyboard.

Is there a way to prevent Google from always listening, without completely disabling the Google app?

Comment: What do you mean it's disabled? I tried it and it works for me. Not sure if you know this but the voice entry does not show up on every text field on Gboard, that's one of the reasons I don't use that keyboard. Are you sure your current text field supports voice entry?

Comment: @SSS The microphone icon appears, but it has not functionality if the Google app is disabled.  BTW, did you find a good keyboard that supports voice entry on every field?  Which one?

Comment: Hmm I see. I personally use SwiftKey which works on every text field, but the voice typing on that seems to be handled by Google as well.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [this website](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/how-to-turn-off-okay-google-always-listening-feature-in-the-google-experience-launcher/) has a guide to the solution that you're looking for.

Edit: I was asked to summarize the site (Yes, I did just copy and paste the instructions for the most part):

Google Now has a neat ability to listen for the “OK, Google” command to automatically launch the app and get you into Search as fast as possible. But, you may not want Google Now to listen to that prompt or hotword for some reason or another. Good news–it’s super easy to turn off!

**Turning off the “OK, Google” hotword**: To turn off the hotword detection, open the Search app. You can find this in your App Drawer, and you can usually access it by holding down the home button as well.

Next, at the top left there’s a hamburger menu. Tap it and head into Settings > Voice.

Next, head into OK, Google Detection. From here, you can toggle it on or off.

Keep in mind that, even if you have it off, you can still head into Google Now and tap the microphone on the right side of the Search bar to use your voice. It’s certainly not as convenient as using the hotword, which gets you into Search right away, but still enables you to use your voice to search.